# How to refactor DB queries for better TTFB in WordPress?

Tags: sql

I was advised to do 3 things to improve my WordPress TTFB:

1. Upgrade PHP --- It is already 7.0 (`apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y` didn't change it from 7.0 last time I checked).
2. Use object caching --- my aim is to use Nginx caching.
3. Refactor DB queries.

I know that refractoring DB queries means to cache DB data, so I won't load it each time anew, till it's expired and re-cached.

How should I correctly do so in WordPress without braking anything?

I ask this since I'm not a SQL expert and I know that databases are very fragile.

Comment: "Refactor db queries" is incredibly broad. Which queries?

Comment: I don't know of anything specific that I should refractor.